# SFDX: How to pull SharingRules from scratch org to local?

Tags: salesforcedx, sharing-rule, apex-sharing

I changed the CustomObject__c OWD to Private. I created a sharing rule through Apex trigger.
When I pulled it, it only pulls the Trigger, Class, and CustomObject__c.meta BUT no sharingRule xml.
That's why when I pushed my changes to Bitbucket, I'm getting these errors:

```
Invalid type: CustomObject__Share
Variable does not exist: share
Variable does not exist: Schema.CustomObject__Share.RowCause
```

What should I do to pull the sharingRules to fix these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Sharing rules are not supported by DX. The DX docs, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_supported_mdapi_types.htm, refer you to the Metadata Data Coverage report:

> Launch the Metadata Coverage report to determine supported metadata
>   for scratch org source tracking purposes. The Metadata Coverage report
>   is the ultimate source of truth for metadata coverage across several
>   channels. These channels include Metadata API, scratch org source
>   tracking, unlocked packages, second-generation managed packages,
>   classic managed packages, and more.

And in the report, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/46, SharingRules are only supported by the Metadata API, not by Source Tracking (which means DX).

[image]